# android text width return 0 even when the view is already created

Tags: android, text, layout, view, paint

I have this code:

```
      public AccountMenuBodyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.account_menu_body, this, true);
        myAccountView = findViewById(R.id.my_account);
      }

      @VisibleForTesting
      String setChipTextWithCorrectLength(String longDesc, String mediumDesc, String shortDesc, int clipWidth) {
        if (textWidthPixels(longDesc) > clipWidth) {
          if (textWidthPixels(mediumDesc) > clipWidth) {
            return shortDesc;
          } else {
            return mediumDesc;
          }
        }
        return longDesc;
      }


  public double textWidthPixels(String text) {
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = myAccountView.getPaint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    return bounds.width();
  }
```

so the inflater create `mAccountView`.

but when i run a unit test, I see `textWidthPixels(..)` returns 0

and `bounds = Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)`

why is it all zero?

test:

```
  @Test
  public void clipWithMediumText() throws Exception {
    String clipText = accountMenuBodyView
        .setChipTextWithCorrectLength("very very very long text", "medium text", "short", 20);
    assertThat(clipText).isEqualTo("medium text");
  }
```

Comment: try getting the width of view instead of text maybe? Are you trying that in an instrumented test?

Comment: it's a unit-test, and i want to compare text width vs view width. no?